# String from Date works, Date from String doesn't work

Tags: xcode, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm taking a NSDate and turning it into a `dateString`. But then...

**When I try to take that same `dateString` and turn it back into a `NSDate` my dates aren't correct.**

*NSDate to `dateString`...*

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy H:mm a"
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeDate as! NSDate)
print("Date: \(dateString)")
```

***Console:***

```
Date: Mar 22, 2016 22:30 PM
Date: Mar 23, 2016 1:00 AM
Date: Mar 23, 2016 9:00 AM
```

*`dateString` to `plainDate`...*

```
let reverseDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
reverseDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy H:mm a"
let plainDate = reverseDateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
print("Date Reverse: \(plainDate)")
```

***Console:***

```
Date Reverse: Optional(2016-03-22 17:30:00 +0000)
Date Reverse: Optional(2016-03-23 05:00:00 +0000)
Date Reverse: Optional(2016-03-23 05:00:00 +0000)
```

Comment: 22:30 pm makes no sense

Comment: You need to decide between 24 "H:mm" or 12 hour "h:mm a" format

Comment: @LeoDabus 22:30 pm makes no sense just because of the "pm" part?

Comment: @LeoDabus The date is getting pulled from CloudKit, which formats it in 24 hour, but when I display the date in a string it would be in 12 hour format, I'm trying to figure out how I would be able to decide between 24 hour and 12 hour in that case.  If you have any suggestions with what I've describe, I'd be happy to hear them, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your converting the Date to a string, your losing the timezone information, and then its not able to piece it back together.

Is there some reason you can't store the Date itself as an NSDate and then use that instead of re-building the date from a string?

If you need to convert it back to the full date from the string, you will need to adjust your format to store the timezone as well

Comment: So the process is: the date+time gets pulled from CloudKit, which is in 24 hour format.  Then I convert that date into a string for the iPhone to display as text (using the users phones time zone so I didn't hardcode the date+time on CloudKit's end). Then I need to pass the string date to the Watch, so I can use that to display as a string and to order timeline entries.

Comment: So where I started running into the problem, was on the Watch side.  So as I was tracing the problem, I figured let me just try this all on the iPhone to see if the problem happens there too when I convert the string back to NSDate.

Comment: I hope that helps and makes it clearer, let me know what you think, if you have suggestions for what I should change or anything else.  Thank you!

Comment: @victorpulak why not store the date as an instance pf NSDate and then pass that to the watch?  then you can still use NSDate to get what you need, and can also format it as a string on the watch?

Comment: I'll try to do that again, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

stringFromDate returns a non-optional string, but dateFromString returns an optional date. Conditionally unwrap the result before printing it out:

> if let result = reverseDateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
>           print(result)
>       }

Comment: Awesome good info! Let me know if you have any thoughts on my main question which is the dates just straight up being different dates though.

Comment: Bolnad already answered this - pass NSDate to the Watch, not the String.

Comment: Ps: or pass timezone info as well

Comment: I'll try to do that again, and I'll also look up how to pass the timezone (as an alternative if I want to do it that way), thanks so much for the help!